# PHP - Serialized xml images replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i have a problem with this: `s:64:"http://urlurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/30.jpg";`

This is a fragment of an xml file with serialized content.
I need to go through entire file and replace every image (jpg or png) with new image. AND: replace `s:64` with my new character count. So I need to replace every instance of `s:whatever` before every jpg or png file and replace image file.

Any ideas with regular expression?

Input:
`s:5:"image";s:51:"http://urlurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/06.jpg";s:7:"id_base";a:6:{s:7:"id_base";s:15:"aq_column_block";s:4:"name";s:6:"Column";s:5:"order";s:1:"6";s:4:"size";s:5:"span4";s:6:"parent";s:1:"0";s:6:"number";s:1:"6";}s:10:"aq_block_9";a:14:{s:7:"content";s:5:"image";s:51:"http://urlurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/10.jpg";`

Desired Output:
`s:5:"image";s:7:"MYIMAGE";s:7:"id_base";a:6:{s:7:"id_base";s:15:"aq_column_block";s:4:"name";s:6:"Column";s:5:"order";s:1:"6";s:4:"size";s:5:"span4";s:6:"parent";s:1:"0";s:6:"number";s:1:"6";}s:10:"aq_block_9";a:14:{s:7:"content";s:5:"image";s:7:"MYIMAGE";`

So basically `s:51:"http://urlurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/06.jpg";` and `s:51:"http://urlurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/10.jpg";` is changed to `s:7:"MYIMAGE";`

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: This seems to be serialized string by native serialization (`serialize` function) of PHP. So you can `unserialize` them, change as you want and serialize back again.

Comment: Not possible. I need to do it with syntax like in my question

Comment: http://ideone.com/ZLrV3g Here's sample. Next time provide what you tried to solve problem. We are not here to do your job.

Comment: I just need that expression, if you dont want to help then dont do it, nobody forces you. btw. works only on one file and what about jpg||png instead of `*` http://codepad.org/Sb800HgR

Comment: http://ideone.com/giufjJ No regex needed. Also read [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: "I need to go through entire file and replace every image (jpg or png) with new image. AND: replace s:64 with my new character count." I need to find jpg or png extensions in a file that have a lot of different code. Code from codepad was just example, sorry about that.

Comment: Regex questions **must** contain: example input, expected output (with precision), tried regular expression. While a PHP question should contain some php code. I don't see any of above.

Answer (score 0):

I have completed this some days ago using notepad ++ search and replace with regex function with these:

for blocks elements: `s:[0-9]+:\"([^s:]*)(\.jpg|\.png)\";`

for normal images: `s:[0-9]+:\"http.*?(\.jpg|\.png)\";`